# How to combine variable name and data-attr in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to do this in SCSS, to apply the background color `$colorState0` dynamically to `elem` class width `data-indx="0"`?

SCSS:

```
$colorState0: rgb(0, 0, 0);
.elem {
 background: $colorState(data-idx);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="elem" data-idx="0"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin). The one below apply the background to the the element that has `elem` class and the given `data-idx`, but you can customise it to your need.

```js
@mixin apply-background($idx) {
   .elem[data-idx="#{$idx}"]{
    background : rgb($idx, $idx, $idx);
   }
}

@include apply-background(0);
```

Comment: SCSS can by concept not create a dynamic solution, because it can only affect the CSS at build-time, not at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this method :

```
$colorState0: rgb(0, 0, 0);
$colorState1: rgb(0, 0, 0);
.elem[data-idx=0] {
 background: $colorState0;
}

.elem[data-idx=1] {
 background: $colorState1;
}
```

and so on